# how to send message to different contact in android at specified time

Tags: android

This apps works for contact number which i enter first...but when i change the contact number and message text...the apps sends a message to first contact number not the changed contact number..
please say how to send a message at different contact at specified time..

My Main class:

```
 public class TimeSms extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button time_btn,date_btn,send_btn,pick_contact;
EditText to,msg_body,time_txt,date_txt;
Calendar calendar;
int hour,min;
int year,month,date;
String recipient,message2,contact,pick_no;
PendingIntent pi;
ArrayList<PendingIntent> pn=new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
ArrayList<PendingIntent> pnn=new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
final static String SENT = "com.dinesg.TimeSms.action.SMS_SENT";
public static final int TIME_DIALOG=0;

public static final int DATE_DIALOG=1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    to=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    msg_body=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    time_txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    date_txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    time_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    date_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    send_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    pick_contact=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    time_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    date_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    send_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    pick_contact.setOnClickListener(this);

    calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    hour=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    date=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    UpdateDate();
    UpdateTime();


}
private void UpdateDate() {

    date_txt.setText(new StringBuilder().append(date).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(year));// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void UpdateTime() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    time_txt.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hour).append(":").append(min));

}
public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time_listen=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        hour=hourOfDay;// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        min=minute;
        UpdateTime();

    }
};

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date_listen=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        year=arg1;
        month=arg2;
        date=arg3;
        UpdateDate();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

    switch(id){
    case TIME_DIALOG:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,time_listen,hour,min,false);
    case DATE_DIALOG:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,date_listen,year,month,date);
    }

    return null;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId())// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG);
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG);
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        recipient=to.getText().toString();
        message2=(msg_body.getText().toString());
        contact=pick_no;
        if(recipient.length()!=0&& message2.length()!=0)
        {   

        Intent b_Intent=new Intent();
        b_Intent.setAction(AlarmService.ACTION);            
        b_Intent.putExtra("RQS", AlarmService.RQS_STOP_SERVICE);

        Intent myIntent=new Intent(this,AlarmService.class);
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sms_number", recipient);
        bundle.putCharSequence("body", message2);
        bundle.putString("contact_choose", contact);            
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);

        pi=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent,0);
        pn.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, b_Intent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        pn.add(pi);
        AlarmManager alarm_manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        calendar.clear();
        alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pi);

        Toast.makeText(this, "your msg will be sending at "+hour+" hours and "+min+" min", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;
    }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "fill both", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    case R.id.button4:
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE); 
        intent.setData(android.provider.Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);   
    }
}



  }
```

MY Service class:

```
     public class AlarmService extends Service{

      String To,message_body,pick;
     NotifyServiceReceiver notifyServiceReceiver;

    final static String ACTION = "NotifyServiceAction";
     final static String STOP_SERVICE = "";
     final static int RQS_STOP_SERVICE = 1;


        private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
       private NotificationManager notificationManager;
         private Notification myNotification;

    SmsManager sms;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    notifyServiceReceiver = new NotifyServiceReceiver();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method 
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "destroy", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

private void CancelService() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION);
    registerReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver, intentFilter);

     Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
    Toast.makeText(this, "service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));


    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED)); 
    sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(bundle.getString("sms_number"), null,(String) bundle.getCharSequence("body") , sentPI, deliveredPI);   


    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
    String notificationText = "Message Notification";
    PendingIntent myIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, People.CONTENT_URI), 0);
    myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,notificationTitle,notificationText, myIntent1);
    notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
    Toast.makeText(this, "your msg will be sending at ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

public class NotifyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int rqs = arg1.getIntExtra("RQS", 0);
         if (rqs == RQS_STOP_SERVICE){
          stopSelf();
         }
    }

}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not sending to the number you change it to or the correct body message is because you are retrieving only the "sms_number"

```
  sms.sendTextMessage(bundle.getString("sms_number"), null,(String) bundle.getCharSequence("body") , sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

As you see you are only getting the "sms_number" out of the bundle. You dont get the contact number as you put in the bundle in the activity.

You should change your code to something like this in your class that sends the message.

```
String contactPicked = bundled.getString("contact_picked");
String recipientEntered = bundle.getString("sms_number");
```

Then you could do a check to see if either is null or doesnt have content and then supply it to the send message method like this..

```
sms.sendTextMessage(contactPicked, null,(String) bundle.getCharSequence("body") , sentPI, deliveredPI);   // or recipient depending which you need to use.
```

Comment: i delete the case R.id.button4: line...Now i enter the Recipient number manually..not switch to contact picker..
my problem when i enter a new number with different text...but the message is goes to first typed number with first text message not new one...

Comment: Are you typing the new number into the same edittext? It should be  recipient=to.getText().toString(); is correct.

Comment: hey..i got the solution..it's all about the PendingIntent..i put 0 in  Flag value.. that's why i getting that problem...
Thank you for your response..All is well:)